# What does “sol en place” mean in this context?

Tags: sens

Here is a piece of text from a Guide to the Installation of Septic Tanks

> Traitement secondaire par le sol en place
>
> Le sol en place est utilisé comme système épurateur (traitement) et comme moyen dispersant (évacuation).

'Septic drain field' or 'leach field' seems right, but I wanted to check that the phrase didn't have some other specific meaning.

Comment: I'd understant the *local* soil. The soil supporting the installation. Therefore, I'd vote for *in-situ*.

Answer (score 1):

As aCOSwt wrote, *sol en place* means local, onsite soil, i.e. the soil that was already there before the facility was installed.

This is in opposition to either a remote soil (unlikely in a septic tank context) or a rebuilt, artificial soil, made from specific materials brought from somewhere else.

Edit: I found [this web page](http://www.rivesdesaone.fr/qu-est-ce-que-l-assainissement-non-collectif-) which supports my interpretation:

> ...deux types de dispositifs peuvent être mis en place pour prétraiter et traiter les eaux usées domestiques.
>   o   Soit par **le sol en place**, ou par **le sol reconstitué** à l’aval d’une fosse septique toutes eaux.
>   ...
>   Les dispositifs de traitement utilisant le **sol en place** sont les tranchées d’épandage à faible profondeur dans **le sol naturel** et les lits d’épandage à faible profondeur. Dans le cas des **sols reconstitués**, les dispositifs sont les suivants : lit filtrant vertical non drainé, **filtre à sable** vertical drainé, lit filtrant drainé à flux vertical à massif de **zéolithe**, et lit filtrant drainé à flux horizontal.

Comment: Really? Neither sounds likely in this context - but I'll take your word for it!